# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IDropdownOption[]'

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, react, fluent-ui

I'm trying to sold a small error in my SPFx Project. I understand the problem, but I can't find any solution.

```
 <DefaultButton className={styles.button} onClick={() => this.addListItems(this.state.data, this.state.selectedDepartmentOptions)}> Eintragen </DefaultButton>

 private addListItems = (user: MicrosoftGraph.User,  selectedDepartmentOptions: IDropdownOption[]): void =>  {

const { selectedRubrikOptions } = this.state;
const departmentKey = user.department;
var isTerminvergabeChecked = (document.getElementById('terminvergabe') as HTMLInputElement | null).checked;
var isHotlineChecked = (document.getElementById('hotline') as HTMLInputElement | null).checked;
let selectedDepartmentText = "";

for (let i = 0; i < selectedDepartmentOptions.length; i++) {
  const option = selectedDepartmentOptions[i];
  console.log(selectedDepartmentOptions[i]);

  if (option.key === departmentKey) {
    selectedDepartmentText = option.text;
    break;
  }
}

if(selectedRubrikOptions === ""){
  alert('Bitte das Pflichtfeld beachten!');

}else{
  sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Laufkundschaft')
  .items.add({
    'Rubrik': selectedRubrikOptions,
    'Au_x00df_enstellen': selectedDepartmentText,
    'Terminvergabe': isTerminvergabeChecked,
    'Hotline': isHotlineChecked,
  })
  .then(()=> alert("Die Daten wurden erfolgreich gespeichert!"));

}
```

I know, the **selectedDepartmentOptions** is a string, the **IDropdownOption[]** is an array. I need this array, because of for loop in "addListitems" Method. But I have defined the IDropdownOption as string.
I understand a problem, but I do not find any solution. Anyone some idea?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have defined `selectedDepartmentOptions` as string in initial state, change it to `IDropdownOption[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your first line to the following.

```
<DefaultButton
    className={styles.button}
    onClick={() => this.addListItems(this.state.data,
      [
        { key: this.state.selectedDepartmentOptions, text: this.state.selectedDepartmentOptions } as IDropdownOption
      ]
    )}> Eintragen </DefaultButton>
```

To explain behind this, you need to convert to a direct array, then add an object inside with JSON schema that is required to form IDropdownOption.